# how to use comparison and 'not' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In my code, I have a list of items:

```
animals = ['LION', 'TIGER', 'DEER', 'CHICKEN']
```

and an empty list:

```
new_catch = []
```

The rest of code:

```
farm =[

    {'LION':'carnivorous', 'legs': 4 , 'strength': 98.7, 'kills': True},
    {'TIGER':'carnivorous', 'legs': 4 , 'strength': 100.18, 'kills': True},
    {'DEER':'harbivorous', 'legs': 4, 'speed': 87.3, 'kills': False},
    {'CHICKEN':'null', 'legs': 2, 'speed': 5, 'strength':2.3, 'kills': False},
    {'PIG': 'omnivorous', 'legs': 4, 'strength': 55.0, 'kills': True, 'speed':64}
]


while not(new_catch in animals):    
       animal = input("give me a:... ").upper()
       for animals in farm:
           for key, value in animals.items():
                 if animal in animals:
                      print('')
                      print("#{}:{}".format(key, value))
                      print('') 


 else:
      new_catch.append(animal)
      print("sorry, {} is not available!!".format(new_catch))
      print(new_catch)
```

I want to call out the names of the animals in the list(animals), but I want to compare the names so that if I call out the name that is not in my list(animals), it gets added to my empty list(new_catch). I am not sure how to phrase it("if not"), but its giving me errors.

Comment: Where does that `else` part belong? Please fix the indentation of the code in your post so that it matches exactly what you are executing on your computer.

Comment: that is exactly where it is on in my code. i put it to execute with the "while not".

Comment: Then you'd have to un-indent it by one space, otherwise it raises an `IndentationError`.

Comment: `new_catch in animals` is checking if a single list *element* is within another list, not if all elements of that list are within the other .... I don't think that's what you intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to do something like this

```
while new_catch != farm:
    name = input("give me a:... ").upper()
    found = False 
    for animals in farm:
        if name in animals:  # Check if that animal name exists as a key 
           found = True 
           print(name)  # print name as a header 
           for key, value in animals.items():
               if key!=name:  # print everything but the name 
                   print("#{}:{}".format(key, value))
           new_catch.append(animal)  # add the entered animal 
           break # end the farm loop since we added an animal 

    # print that we can't find the input, and repeat the while loop 
    if not found:
        print("sorry, we do not have a {} yet!".format(animal)) 
        new_catch.append(animal)  #add the input list

    print("Caught so far: {}".format(new_catch))
```

Comment: thanx, _007. though it removes the first value of each key, i will have to figure that one out. your correction is pretty good

Comment: What do you mean "removes the first value"? Just remove the `if key!=name` check

Comment: made a few changes: <blink><br/>  "
        if animal in animals:
            found = True
            print(animal)
            for key, value in animals.items():
                if key != animal:
                    print("#{}:{}".format(key, value))
                    print('')
           
   
    if not found:
        print("sorry, we do not have a {} yet!".format(animal))
        new_catch.append(animal)#add the input to empty list
        print(new_catch)"</blink>

Comment: You can't really format comments. I'm not sure what you're trying to show exactly, but there is an [edit link under your question above](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49897571/edit)

Answer (score 0):

First, I think the problem with the error you're seeing is that you've declared "animals" twice here, once as a list, and once as an index in the while loop. It's going to think you're trying to hash in a list. Try giving the second declaration a unique name.

Second, are you actually doing anything with the new_catch list, or just adding new inputs to it where applicable. If so, you need to make the while more generic to make sure there's a continued cycle of input/output, but also move all the conditions to *after* the input call.

```
while True:    
  animal = input("give me a:... ").upper()
  for farmAnimals in farm:
   for key, value in farmAnimals.items():
      if animal in farmAnimals:
         print('')
         print("#{}:{}".format(key, value))
         print('') 
      else:
        if not (animal in new_catch):
          new_catch.append(animal)
          print("sorry, {} is not available!!".format(animal))
          print(animal)
```

Comment: it brought back a     "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\dell\Desktop\Locale\packages\animals2.py", line 38, in <module>    while not(new_catch in animals):TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'PS C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Locale\packages>"              but i also need it to add the new inputs to my empty list